# Powershell Where-Object and DN exclusions

Tags: powershell

I am trying to query a list of users while excluding a specific OU. This is also using Quest's AD snap-in for Get-QADUser. I have this:

```
$ExcludedOU = "Service Accounts"

$inactiveUsers = Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 3 -SearchRoot $sourceOu -NotLoggedOnFor $InactiveFor -Enabled | Where-Object {$_.description -notlike $DescriptionPrefix -and @{n="ParentContainerDN";e={($_.ParentContainerDN -split ",*..=")[0]}} -notlike $ExcludedOU }
```

The goal is to exclude any users where the parent OU is "Service Accounts". ParentContainerDN looks like `OU=Service Accounts,OU=Our Users,DC=DOMAINNAME,DC=ORG`

This query does not error, but it does not exclude either. This is the part I may not have the syntax correct on?

```
@{n="ParentContainerDN";e={($_.ParentContainerDN -split ",*..=")[0]}} -notlike $ExcludedOU
```

Comment: @Matt Weird, that's the accepted solution syntax here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2b0251a7-30cf-4bc5-a3fe-7a1e8605bed0/export-users-from-ad-specific-parameters?forum=winserverDS

Comment: That maybe be true but it is used how I said in that question as part of select... not in the where itself. In the where you appear to be defining a hashtable and not actually using a calculated property. Be back soon to help more.

Comment: If I read the link correctly, you should have taken item [1] from the array, where object [0] is empty.

Comment: @KaiZhao I started off trying [1] and same result. Nothing was filtered out.

Comment: what if make it `-and (($_.ParentContainerDN -split ",*..=")[1] -notlike $ExcludedOU)`

Comment: @Matt I'm a bit confused about using select. I thought select just pulls out a specific data segment for printing. It doesn't actually filter anything out of the list?

Comment: @KaiZhao Looks like that works. That syntax makes sense.

Comment: NVM what I said about the regex query. That was done on purpose and I even got part of it wrong. I know  your issue here is your use of the calculated property syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was partially wrong about the regex portion of your split. I am still correct in that the string supports regular expressions. That query will split on the  CN=, OU= and DN=.

However you placed [calculated property syntax](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx) into a `where-object` clause. It didn't error out since it is a valid **hashtable** and hashtables support `like` and `notlike`. Calculated properties are used for things like `Format-Table` and `Select-Object` which you can then reference those "new" properties later in other pipes.

```
$inactiveUsers = Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 3 -SearchRoot $sourceOu -NotLoggedOnFor $InactiveFor -Enabled | 
    Select-Obejct Name,SamAccountName,Description,@{n="ParentContainerDN";e={($_.ParentContainerDN -split ",*..=")[0]}} |
    Where-Object {$_.description -notlike $DescriptionPrefix -and $_.ParentContainerDN -notlike $ExcludedOU }
```

The above syntax is what was also done in the [code you linked to on Social Technet](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/2b0251a7-30cf-4bc5-a3fe-7a1e8605bed0/export-users-from-ad-specific-parameters?forum=winserverDS)

I cannot make this return false for the life of me. This will evaluate to true which might be why your query was not working as expected. This is valid PowerShell just not correct to use.

```
@{n="ParentContainerDN";e={$_.WhatEver}} -notlike "string"
```

---

However like [Kai Zhao mentioned in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698617/powershell-where-object-and-dn-exclusions?noredirect=1#comment60990999_36698617) this is not really used effectively and you can get the same results without the calculated property.

```
$inactiveUsers = Get-QADUser -SizeLimit 3 -SearchRoot $sourceOu -NotLoggedOnFor $InactiveFor -Enabled |
    Where-Object {$_.description -notlike $DescriptionPrefix -and ($_.ParentContainerDN -split ",*..=")[1] -notlike $ExcludedOU}
```